# Difference between Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory and Java.Lang.Object.BitmapFactory

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin to create an Android app and am confused about the mappings between

- Java.Lang.Object.BitmapFactory
- Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory

The .NET System.Drawing.Bitmap doesn't appear, so I think that porting code would only get confused by these two instances.

Can anyone explain when I should use one vs the other in the generic sense (this overlap between Android and Java extends to more than just these named classes)

Comment: I don't see any Java.Lang.Object.BitmapFactory. Is that a typo? For any Bitmap related tasks, you are supposed to you Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory. Docs are at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html